# MaterialDialog autoDismiss() vs canceledOnTouchOutside() in Android

Tags: android, android-dialog

I want to close the Dialog UI when the user clicks outside of the Dialog. For that, I found two functions `autoDismiss()` and `canceledOnTouchOutside()`. Both seems to work for my case. But what is the difference between two?

Answer (score 2):

Method **autoDismiss()** and **canceledOnTouchOutside()** are same as below

**[dismiss ()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#dismiss())**

> Dismiss this dialog, removing it from the screen. This method can be
>   invoked safely from any thread. Note that you should not override this
>   method to do cleanup when the dialog is dismissed, instead implement
>   that in onStop().

**[setCanceledOnTouchOutside](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setCanceledOnTouchOutside(boolean))**

> Sets whether this dialog is canceled when touched outside the window's
>   bounds. If setting to true, the dialog is set to be cancelable if not
>   already set .

Comment: Hi Amiya, 
Thanks for the explanation. But I believe I said autoDismiss() but you have given an explanation for dismiss().

Comment: `autoDismiss()` i did not  use that yet . I assume it's a property of `Material Dialog` . Logic should be same .